# Adding values to end of a nested tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I have a nested tuple in the form:

```
nested_tup = [('15MAR18 103000', '15MAR18 103758'), ('15MAR18 120518', '15MAR18 121308')] etc...
```

The 1st element in each tuple is the start date and the 2nd element in each tuple is the end date.

I want to find the difference in time between the 2 dates and then append the answer as a 3rd element in each tuple... So far I have the following:

```
for start, end in nested_tup:
     after = datetime.strptime(end, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
     before = datetime.strptime(start, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
     duration = after - before
```

I need this duration value to be appended as the 3rd element in each tuple.. I don't know how though..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your 'nested tuple' is a list containing tuples, since you can't add values to a tuple, I'd suggest you to just replace your tuples by lists and add the third value to those lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(nested_tup):
     after = datetime.strptime(end, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
     before = datetime.strptime(start, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
     duration = after - before
     nested_tup[i] += (duration, )
```

which could be slightly easier to read as:

```
f = '%d%b%y %H%M%S'
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(nested_tup):
     nested_tup[i] += (datetime.strptime(end, f) - datetime.strptime(start, f), )
```

Even though you cannot mutate `tuple` objects to append a new component, you can concatenate `tuple` objects using `+`, which creates a new `tuple` from the constituent `tuple` objects, and this is perfectly good for your problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map in combination with a conversion function.

```
def convert(tup):
  after = datetime.strptime(tup[1], '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
  before = datetime.strptime(tup[0], '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
  duration = after - before
  return (tup[0], tup[1], duration)

ans = list(map(convert, nested_tup))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable data structure. So you cannot append values to tuple. 
[Check out immutable sequence types.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types)

This may work for you,

```
strptime = lambda dt: datetime.strptime(dt, f)
[(start, end, strptime(end) - strptime(start)) for start, end in nested_tup]
```